# Any way to change routes || state by directive in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a simple tab directive and I need a way to create custom routes by this directive attributes. I know I can create routes by `app.config( function ($stateProvider) {...} )`, but it doesn't work inside `link` directive function. Is there any way to do it?

> **UPDATE**: made simple example what I mean
>   https://plnkr.co/edit/ZNDcZc217H2PRVHYWLA7?p=preview

```
myApp.directive('navTab', ["$compile", function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      myApp.config( function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state({
          name: attrs.sref,
          url: attrs.sref,
          template: 'Hello!'
        });
      });
      element.replaceWith('<a ui-sref="'+attrs.sref+'">Hello '+attrs.sref+'</a>');
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: It is hard to help with a bug in code when the question does not include any of the buggy code.

Comment: @georgeawg updated with plunker example

Comment: The short answer is NO. The AngularJS framework executes in two phases, the config phase and the run phase. The configuration (including the $state table) can not be modified once the run phase starts. Directives are compiled during run phase. Directives can not modify the $state table. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependencies and Order of execution](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#dependencies-and-order-of-execution).